# Google translator API problem with MAC and IPAD

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, ipad, google-translation-api

I am using google translator API to convert English to Spanish based on user preference. It's working fine in any windows system. But I am facing problems with IPAD and MAC. It seems that it's getting converted to Spanish automatically.

I am doing the following

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
// Update
new google.translate.TranslateElement(
    { pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT },
    'google_translate_element'
);}
```

On page load

```
$(document).ready(() => {
changeLanguage();});

function changeLanguage() {
let currentLang = searchParams.get('language');
$(`[data-lang='${currentLang}']`).addClass('active');
window.location = `#googtrans(en|${currentLang})`;
setTimeout(() => {
    $('body').show();
}, 1000);}
```

The code is working in all systems except IPAD and MAC. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding #googtrans(en|${preferredLanguage}) with the URL.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FGTranslator](https://github.com/gpolak/FGTranslator) for it to be easier to achieve what you are looking for. Additionally, here is the code that you might want to use for your coding:

```
FGTranslator *translator = [[FGTranslator alloc] initWithGoogleAPIKey:@"your_google_key"];

[translator translateText:@"Bonjour!" 
               completion:^(NSError *error, NSString *translated, NSString *sourceLanguage)
{
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"translation failed with error: %@", error);
    else
        NSLog(@"translated from %@: %@", sourceLanguage, translated);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, although it's not an option for me at the moment to change the library. Are there any bugs with google translator API with MAC / IPAD which causing this typical situation?

Are there any guide/help available? Please let me know 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on some research I did there seems to be some error of implementing iOS and they suggest to use another library to achieve what you need.